# UIKeyboardAppearance lag on iOS 7

Tags: ios, uikeyboard

If application uses UIKeyboardAppearanceDark for some UIKeyInput, after leaving app in the background and then it becomes first responder, keyboard appears as white for 1 seconds. This bug really annoys when whole application is in dark style. Is there any way to bypass it?

Comment: Not a complete thought, but what would happen if you used the app delegate entering foreground methods to send it a message to become first responder ?

Comment: I tried to do it in applicationDidBecomeActive. When app opens keyboard already black. But the problem that i don't need it opened all the time. if i call resignFirstResponder right after that, keyboard still appears white when i tap on input. I also tried calling resignFirstResponder after some delay. But this do not work for small delays. With longer delays i see keyboard appearance/disappearance and it still appears white of course.